Displaying source code from multiple files in a Quarto HTML document
I'm using Quarto to create a portable HTML report, and I'd like to display the source code from two different files: one for data cleaning (data_cleaning.R) and another for the Quarto report (report.qmd).
I’ve tried something like this:
format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
    code-tools:
      source: data_cleaning.R
      source: report.qmd

But it throws an error on render. Is there any way to display source code from both files in the same document? Or perhaps another approach to incorporate multiple files into the report to ensure full reproducibility?
Link to documentation: https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-code.html#code-tools

The source option in the YAML front matter is primarily meant as a way to show only the code for the current document (i.e., the QMD that the html file was rendered from).
If you want to show text from multiple sources files, such as in the case that you have multiple steps in the data analysis, you can use Quarto's native includes shortcodes. Read that documentation for more detail; but as an example for you:
I have 3 files: report.qmd, _data_cleaning.R, and _data_analysis.R. I want to include the source code from the 2 R scripts into my Quarto document.
_data_cleaning.R
print("cleaning")

_data_analysis.R
print("analysis")

report.qmd
```{r}
{{< include _data_cleaning.R >}}
{{< include _data_analysis.R >}}
```

report.html

